# Find CT Fourier transform of $ \left[ \frac{ \sin(\pi ~ t) }{\pi ~t} \right] \left[ \frac{ \sin(2\pi ~ (t-1)) }{\pi ~(t-1)} \right] $using properties

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier

Use properties of Fourier Transform to solve the question.
The question is in the imgur link below.

I got $f_t$ of $\frac {sin(pi \cdot t)}  {pi \cdot t}$ as rectangular pulse with value $1$ from -pi to pi
second ft is $e^{-jw}$ from $-2 \pi$ to $2 \pi$.
I'm unable to get the resultant of two of them

Comment: We don't solve other people's homework when they don't even show any own attempt and explain exactly what they personally need help with. In fact, we have a question close reason for exactly that.

Comment: Also use some Latex to clarify that equation. Are all those " * " s stand for "multiplication" ? Or is one of them a convolution ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbkj4.png  link of question